# When displaying a content type only show one of two fields depending on user logged in?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Using Orchard 1.6...I have setup a form to display from the front end, displaying content type 'Booking', which displays a hyperlink field 'Book Now'.

If the user is logged in it takes them to the booking page, if not the Access Denied/register page appears(when the hyperlink is clicked) with error: Cannot create content. Anonymous users do not have Submit_PodAvailability permission.

This is OK but I want to tidy it up. Is it possible to check if the user is logged in when the original form loads...if they are show the hyperlink 'Book' and if they are not, instead show the hyperlink 'Login to Book'

Comment: You can use Layers, using rules. Using authenticated rule for that url. For example authenticated and url("~/home")), in this case you can show the Form as this layer is going to be active just for authenticated users. Docs : http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets

Comment: When you say "hyperlink field", are you actually referring to a content field that renders as a hyperlink field? If so, override its view and surround the markup with this: @if(WorkContext.CurrentUser != null) { <a href="#">@T("Book Now")</a> }